# Do i need to release acquired resources in react-native?

Tags: react-native, resources

I am opening DB(`react-native-sqlite-storage`) on the start of app.
I wonder do I need to close DB on the exit from the app,
if so how to detect that app is closing?

And more generic question:
how to handle resource management, is it required or everything done automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if it's necessary to close your DB, but if you would like to you can use the AppState component that comes natively with React Native to tell when the application is inactive (closed) https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html

also here is another answer that looks pretty similar to this [How to detect when a React Native app is closed (not suspended)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38962034/how-to-detect-when-a-react-native-app-is-closed-not-suspended)

Basically
1) Add an event listener in your componentDidMount method so as soon as the component is rendered it knows to pay attention to whenever the app state "change"s.

2) whatever callback you assign to the on change method, within that method you can check if the app state is "inactive".