# React appevent termination

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to find a way to execute a function upon termination of the app, what function can I use to do this in react native?

Basically, whenever the user closes the app (completely terminate).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect when a React Native app is closed (not suspended)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38962034/how-to-detect-when-a-react-native-app-is-closed-not-suspended)

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
AppState.addEventListener('change', state => {
  if (state === 'active') {
    // do this
  } else if (state === 'background') {
    // do that
  } else if (state === 'inactive') {
    // do that other thing
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AppState API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html) provided by `react-native` in your root component where you register/mount your app.

There you can add an `onChange` eventlistener to `AppState` which executes your custom function whenever `AppState.currentState.match(/inactive|background/)` returns `true`. Your custom function however should be isolated from your other component states.