# Store data while app is running [React Native]

Tags: react-native, variables, session

I'm trying to set a variable in my app which is active only while the app is running and will be destroyed when the app is exited. The concept is something like session in web browser where the session will be destroyed only when the browser is closed.

For some reason I cannot use `state` as it will get renewed when there is `dispatch` action triggered. I had a thought of using `AsyncStorage.setItem()` but it doesn't work in my situation too as it is storing the variable in the device. Else there is a way to do `removeItem` when the app is exiting without triggering any button.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38962034/how-to-detect-when-a-react-native-app-is-closed-not-suspended

Answer (score 0):

Use redux as this does have the same behaviour what you want. you can store in a store and it gets destroyed when app is exited.

Comment: I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out above in a comment, it looks like the [`AppState`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate) API is your friend here. Untested example code:

```
class AppStateExample extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.temp = "something"
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
  }

  handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    if (nextAppState.match(/inactive|background/)) {
      this.temp = null
    }
  };
```

}