# How to detect an application in the kill app on react native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I want to change the state data from the API when the application is killed by the user.

I have tried using the componentWillUnmount to change data when the application closes, I also use the AppState

```
  _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    if (
      this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) &&
      nextAppState === 'active'
    ) {
      console.log('App has come to the foreground!')
    }
    this.setState({ appState: nextAppState })
  }
```

I want that when the application is killed by the user, it can change the state automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try This :

```
componentDidMount() {
   AppState.addEventListener('change', 
   this.handleAppStateChange);
  }

componentWillUnmount() {
  AppState.removeEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
}

handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
   if (nextAppState === 'inactive') {
   console.log('the app is closed');
  }    
 }
```

Comment: it run on IOS, but don't run on Android. Do you have any idea for Android.

Comment: it works in both case android and ios , i have checked already

Comment: @user3751548 I am having same problem any solution for this? Please Help

Comment: check which states are available for android and ios https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate

Answer (score 12):

`nextAppState === 'inactive'` or checking if `background` does not tell you if the app is "Killed" (swiped out) or not.

Because when the native layer is killed then the javascript engine is killed as well. So there is no way to tell javascript that the app is killed.

If you just want to initialize something after the app is killed, you can fire some function inside `constructor` or `componentDidMount` of a base component which you know that it will be mounted only once for your app.

added: Now we may (maybe prefer to) use `useEffect(()=>{}, [])` instead of examples above.

If you really want to make sure the app is killed before, maybe you can store `nextAppState` into some persisted store and check if the value matched one of inactive or background since the app state will not be changed on the initial startup of the app.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using express package as node server for your API,
and i hope you are treat before with web-scokets then

i suggest to check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69006822/16800675)