# How can I run code before my React Native app completely closes?

Tags: react-native

Can't figure out how to run code before my React Native App closes completely (not backgrounded.) Tried using AppState, and the "Inactive" state doesn't apply to this case.

Tried using Inactive, but again, it doesn't run when the app is closed. Currently using Expo Go to test the app.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is not possible check the answer here for alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60517795/16967562

Answer (score 0):

you should use `AppState` api of react native, follow the example in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44508603/20587701)

Answer (score 0):

we can achieve this using `componentwillunmount` or `useEffect` hook return function in our root(App) component.

```
const App=()=>{
   useEffect(()=>{
     console.log("Mount");
     return ()=>{
        console.log("this will execute right before app close.");
     }
   },[])
}
```