# React-Native - Is there a way to identify if app is opened from killed state

Tags: react-native

I need to identify whether app is opened from killed state.

Checked the AppState module in React Native,
But getting error in Android
It is not giving back "Inactive" state. Please let me know a solution, if there?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, AppState } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
    const [initialAppState, setInitialAppState] = useState(AppState.currentState);

    const handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
        if (initialAppState === 'inactive' && nextAppState === 'active') {
            // App was opened from a killed state. ****Issue in android - this is not called*****
            console.log('App was opened from a killed state.');
        } else if (initialAppState === 'background' && nextAppState === 'active') {
            // App was opened from a background state.
            console.log('App was opened from a background state.');
        }

        setInitialAppState(nextAppState);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const appStateSubscription = AppState.addEventListener('change', handleAppStateChange);

        return () => {
            appStateSubscription.remove();
        };
    }, [initialAppState]);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect an application in the kill app on react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58461255/how-to-detect-an-application-in-the-kill-app-on-react-native)

Comment: Could you try by passing "inactive" as initial state => `const [initialAppState, setInitialAppState] = useState("inactive");`