# How to have page re-rendered after exiting and re-opening the app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

This seems to be a dumb question, but I didn't find a one in SO.

Here is it:

I have a react native app. Every time I exit the app and re-open it, I expect to have Home page as the default screen being displayed, and also re-render the Home page as `componentDidMount` inside the Home screen will fetch latest data from the database. How can we achieve such case? Thanks!

Comment: what I mean exit is just put app in the background, not mean sign out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mean closing the app and rather just sending it to the background, you can use the exported [`AppState`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html) object to detect it. See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38962034/how-to-detect-when-a-react-native-app-is-closed-not-suspended) for an example. Once you detect the event, you can force a rerender using `forceUpdate()` for class components, or by using a dummy hook in functional components

Slightly modified React docs example:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppState, Text} from 'react-native';

class AppStateExample extends Component {
  state = {
    appState: AppState.currentState,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
  }

  _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    if (
      this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) &&
      nextAppState === 'active'
    ) {
      console.log('App has come to the foreground!');
      this.forceUpdate();
    }
    this.setState({appState: nextAppState});
  };

  render() {
    return <Text>Current state is: {this.state.appState}</Text>;
  }
}
```

Functional component (untested):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { AppState } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const [updateVal, setUpdateVal] = useState(false);
  const forceUpdate = newState => {
    if (newState === 'active')
      setUpdateVal(!updateVal); // forces a rerender
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', forceUpdate);
    return () => AppState.removeEventListener('change', forceUpdate);
  }, []);
  // return your contents
};
```

However, if you're actually *closing* it (not just leaving the app), it should rerender.

Comment: Are those equivalent? I don't understand why in the class version you have to check for inactive/background? Wouldn't it work without it?

Comment: I believe that functional component renders at least one time too many (forces rerender when 'change' fires for 'unknown' to 'active' case.

Comment: The first one is directly copied from the React docs. I wrote the second one based on my own knowledge. I don't know why the React developers did it the way they did either, but I don't feel like messing with it. I've never seen the state be `'unknown'` personally, but if that's an issue you face. there are many ways to rework the code to ignore that case.

Answer (score 1):

Apps have a different concept of "exiting" that might be unintuitive.  If you close out of an app it is still open in the background, which is why your app doesn't start up from scratch the next time you open it.

To handle that situation you need to watch for activity instead and you cannot depend on React lifecycle events like you would in a browser app.

For example if you use React-navigation you could use their lifecycle events: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-lifecycle.html

Which include things like `willFocus, willBlur, didFocus and didBlur`.  Then, based on those events you can run whatever code you need, such as updating some state or fetching new data.