# react native - how to detect when user quits app

Tags: react-native

I have code in place to ensure that app keeps running when user moves app to background *(i.e. when user clicks home button in IOS or "swipes up" in IOS)*.
HOWEVER if user actually **quits** app I want to warn them that the background program will not longer run.
  Is there any way to run a callback function when user actually tries to quit?

Comment: I understand that you want to handle the app state change right?, if these the case maight this can help you https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.66/appstate

Comment: it is duplicate, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38962034/how-to-detect-when-a-react-native-app-is-closed-not-suspended)..